# Unable to add android project to GitHub account in Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I tried to add my Android project to my Github account using Android Studio's

```
VCS -> Import into Version control -> Share project on github
```

However, I am getting this https://github.com/vkrpro/Musica.

I tried the solution recommended, but I am still not able to create my repositories. After that I deleted my empty repositories, but I am still seeing the commit command on Android Studio. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. VCS -> select "Enable Version Control"

   2. Then in the left panel click on Android and select Project
   3. Then right click on the name of the project then from menu select Git -> sekect "Add".
   4. After all the files are added go to VcS -> Select "Commit".
   5. Add a message then select commit and push at bottom of the dialog which has appeared.
   6. A dialog will open where you should define remote and add the link of you directory created in git hub.
   7. Then select "Push" at bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried many times to create my repository but i failed . Successfully added my project on github  https://github.com/vkrpro/Musica

Answer (score 0):

you can only import a project from VCS if you have already created it. to do that you first need to create a repository on  [Github](http://github.com)

commit your work then push to the remote Github repository. you can then link your local and remote work using VCS.